# form action with php page not working whlile using bootstrap framework

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to create navigation and mixing html with it to create form but when I am submitting my form the form action in which it should print done showing a blank page  .
Here in this code when i submitting the form php page is no working it is showing blank page  . 
Please Help

```
<div class="container">
      <h2>Small Geeks</h2>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#addscript">Add Script</a></li>


      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
          <h3>HOME</h3>
          <p>home page
        </div>

        <div id="addscript" class="tab-pane fade">


    <div id="addscriptcontainer">

    <form action="createscript.php"method="POST">

    <input type="text" size="100" id="question"placeholder="Your Program Question"required><br><br>

     <textarea  rows="10" cols="150" wrap="hard"id="program"placeholder="Your Program Here"required></textarea><br><br>


      Select Language:<br>
      <select name="language">
        <option value=1>C</option>
        <option value=2>C++</option>
        <option value=3>Java</option>
        <option value=4>Java Script</option>
      </select>
    <br><br>

    Select Level:<br>  
    <select name="level" >
        <option value=1>Beginner</option>
        <option value=2>Intermediate</option>
        <option value=3>Advance</option>

      </select>
      <br><br>

    <input type="text"  id="name"placeholder="Your Name"required><br><br>

    <button type="submit"value="submit">Submit</button>

    </form>
    </div>
```

And here is my php page which is given in form action  but it is showing a blank page please help

```
<?php
echo "done";
?>
```

Comment: anything in the browser console?

Comment: what stands in the browser address bar?

Comment: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/thisone/name.php   simple it is not performing php script after submitting through submit button it is showing blank response

Comment: Seems you are running the files from local storage instead of using your XAMPP server, try using the loopback address in your browser `127.0.0.1`

Comment: yeh !!! done !! thankyou so much Michael sir :-)

Comment: @NamitPathak no problem, always happy to help. I have created a new answer with the solution, please mark it as the answer if I have resolved the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your comments on the original post.

You are using the local storage to access your files, you will need to access your webserver (XAMPP).

Try using the loopback address in your browser: either `http://127.0.0.1/` or `http://localhost/`